# R: Suppress axes in addtable2plot{plotrix}

Tags: r

I am trying to add a table to a plot with `addtable2plot()`. But I am running into a peculiar problem, viz. it's overriding the options in `plot()`. If I do:

```
plot(seq(1:10), axes=F)
```

the axes labels, ticks etc. are not printed. But if I then add:

```
addtable2plot(x=.8*max(axis(1)), y=.7*max(axis(2)), data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow=3)))
```

the axes etc. get printed automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because you call `axis()`. Use `axTicks(1)` instead.

Comment: Perfect! Many thanks, batiste. Btw...How does one know something like this? This seems ridiculously obscure.

Comment: when random guesses fail to convince R, careful reading of the documentation often helps.